# Apex, How to create navigation menu with pictures?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Apex application with a sidebar navigation menu like this :

[image]

Is possible to replace these font awesome icons by some png pictures ?

I have tried the put an image tag in the list item configuration but it didn't work :

```
 <img src="#APP_IMAGES#fullheart.png"/>
```

The HTML generated is wrong :

```
<span class="fa <img src=&quot;myapp/r/13002/files/static/v1152/fullheart.png&quot;/>"></span>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generated HTML is wrong because you put an HTML code into a place where APEX engine expects to find a CSS class name.

To replace a standard icon with custom one, you need to do the following:

- Go to "Shared Components" -> "Templates", find there a page template which you are using, click on the name to edit.
- Go to tab "Cascading Style Sheets" -> "Inline"
- Put there a CSS code like this:

  ```
  .my_icon {
      background-image: url("#APP_IMAGES#fullheart.png");
  }
  ```
- Return to the Navigation Menu Item properties, and put the CSS class name (`my_icon`) into "Image/Class" property.

If you use several page templates, you need to edit all of them.